# Make Xamarin button the size of its text but no bigger

Tags: xamarin

I create the following button in a Xamarin Portable Class Library app

```
Content = new Button { Text = "Up", HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,  MinimumWidthRequest = 0, MinimumHeightRequest = 0 };
```

This give me a button that looks like this

[image: Xamarin button that its bigger than its text]

I want one that looks more like this

[image: Button that is sized to its text]

This is quite easy to do in native Android layouts (RelativeLayout and LinearLayout etc).

I have tried a million things but I can't get it to happen in Xamarin, does anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a way to set the Padding property on the button, which is not available in Forms. Here's a [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21691/how-to-set-padding-of-button) to a Xamarin forums post where someone had a question similar to yours and the answer, as of now, is to create a custom renderer.